# How to get the correct HTTP POST status code between Node.js express and jQuery client

Tags: jquery, node.js, post, express, http-status

In a Node.js app running Express, I have a route setup to take POST requests and create database objects.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // create object in DB
    res.send('');
    res.status(201).end();
});
```

I understand a [201 status code](https://httpstatuses.com/201) indicates successful creation of the object. I wish to receive a 201 status in my jQuery POST on the client side:

```
$.post('/', sendData).done(function(receiveData, status, xhr) {
    alert(xhr.status); // returns 200 status
});
```

However, I am receiving a 200 status, not the 201 I am trying to send.

**What can I change to receive at the client the 201 status code I am trying to send from the server?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send)

Try setting the status before sending:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // create object in DB
    res.status(201).send('');
});
```